# Monte Carlo Sampling with non-uniform distributions?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, sampling, monte-carlo

I'm currently studying Monte Carlo sampling, referencing [Veach's "Robust Monte Carlo Methods for Light Transport Simulation"](https://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/veach_thesis/thesis.pdf).

On page 63, he writes:

> The idea of Monte Carlo integration is to evaluate the integral
>
> $I = \int_{\Omega}f(x)d\mu(x) $
>
> using random sampling. In its basic form, this is done by independently sampling $N$ points $X_1, ..., X_N$ according to some convenient density function $p$, and then computing the estimate
>
> $F_N = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{f(X_i)}{p(X_i)}$

I've been playing around with this, and I understand the the technique when using uniform sampling on arbitrary domains $\Omega=[a, b]$, where $p(X_i) = \frac{1}{b-a}$. I've written a small python test program and it seems to work well.

However, I'm confused by his statement regarding "independently sampling $N$ points $X_1, ..., X_N$ **according to some convenient density function $p$**".

I'm assuming this means I can choose any arbitrary probability density function I want for $p(X_i)$?

As a simple test, I chose the Gaussian distribution $N(0.5, 0.15)$ to get a PDF centered at $0.5$ and roughly fitted to the interval $[0,1]$. To me, this seems "convenient".

I'm trying to apply the formula by drawing samples $X_i$ using this PDF, and for each iteration of the summation I can evaluate the integrand at each sample as $f(X_i)$, and divide by the probability $p(X_i)$ of each chosen sample.

For simplicity, I'm attempting to integrate trivial functions such as $f(x) = 1$, and $f(x) = x$ etc.

However, this does not seem to work at all, and I get values significantly different from the true value of the integral (eg. we expect $\int_{0}^{1}1 = 1$, $\int_{0}^{1}x = 0.5$), even with large samples sizes of $N = 100,000$ etc. The values I get are off by ~1, and vary noticeably between runs.

I suspect 1 of 2 things: either MC integration of this form requires uniform sampling, or I'm misunderstanding something... I'd appreciate any insights you may have!

Comment: You're using a different measure $\mu$.

Comment: Hmm, how so? $\mu = 0.5$ is the center of the interval $[0,1]$

Comment: Do you understand what the $\mathrm{d}\mu(x)$ means in the integral?  Why are you expecting to calculate $\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ if you don't use a uniform distribution?

Comment: Thank you - Now that you point it out, no, I don't think I understand that. I read $d\mu(x)$ as "change in $\mu$ as a function of x", but I'm not really sure how to interpret that. I glossed over it, since I'm trying to implement the approximation $F_N$.

I'd appreciate any insight you have on this. Are you saying that I can **only** use a uniform distribution?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.  $\mathrm{d}x$ means a uniform distribution is the only appropriate one.  You can read about probability distributions to understand more about what $\mathrm{d}\mu$ means.

Comment: Thanks again - can you suggest any resources on where I might start to find out more? I'm not sure what to ask/google, and now that I'm thinking about it, this is the first time I recall seeing this notation.

Also, I'm confused: You mention **dx** now, but that's not actually mentioned anywhere in my OP.

Comment: Google "probability distribution"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108135/discussion-between-b1skit-and-saulspatz).

Comment: There isn't a short answer to this.  You have to read about probability distributions, particularly continuous distributions, in order to understand.  Alternatively, you could look up Riemann-Stieltjes integrals, but that would probably be a harder path.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I'm familiar with continuous probability distributions, it's just the specific notation $d\mu(x)$ I've not seen before. It doesn't appear in any of my textbooks, nor in any of the first page google results.

Comment: Just pretend it says $dF(x)$ instead of $d\mu(x)$.  Obviously the expectation of a random variable depends on its distribution.

Answer (score 0):

For example, to compute $\int_0^2f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ you might compute $\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ with $1000$ samples and spearately compute $\int_1^2f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ with $2000$ samples (because the function is "wilder" over that interval and needs more sample for an equally reliable result) and add the parts. This is equivalent to making $3000$ samples over the original interval $[0,2]$ but *weighting* the samples differently, namely assign twice the weight to those samples in the subinterval with half the probability density (which also means that the weighted number of samples becomes $\sim 4000$). Taking this further, you can use any other nice probability density and the induced weighting by the reciprocal of the density.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this is the problem. For example, I'm trying to integrate the function $f(x) = 1$, which is a perfectly flat line, yet the technique doesn't seem to work.